# AngularJS: Hashbang URL keeps appending to itself on full refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularJS app, configured with the following:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

So in modern browsers, it works with pushstate no problem, an example URL would be:

```
http://myapp.com/members
```

In older browsers, e.g. IE9, when I browse to that URL, it rewrites it as expected to:

```
http://myapp.com/members#!/members
```

Clicking any links from this point on uses the hashbang method, also correctly:

```
http://myapp.com/members#!/members/add
```

However...

If I full reload a page once it's on a hashbang rewritten url, it will keep appending the hash to itself. First refresh:

```
http://myapp.com/members#!/members#!/members#!%2Fmembers
```

.. and second refresh:

```
http://myapp.com/members#!/members#!/members#!%2Fmembers#!/members#!%2Fmembers%23!%2Fmembers%23!%2Fmembers
```

What is going on here that could be causing this? Usually it won't happen as people will navigate within the app and angular will handle the urls, but doing a full reload seems to break it.  Thanks.

Comment: "In older browsers, e.g. IE9"
Well there's your problem! LOL (I know, not helpful, but as penance, now I'll go and look for our shim code on this.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting

```
<base href="/" />
```

in the head? It may be an angular 1.1.5 bug/feature.

Comment: THANK YOU! Even on modern browsers that support the History API, the hashbang url wouldn't rewrite correctly to the non-hashbang url. I spent too much time banging my head on this, but now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Note that in angular 1.2, declaring a base url is not recommended anymore actually http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

Comment: Note that in Angular 1.3+, declaring a base url **IS** recommended: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

Answer (score 1):

Placing a `<base>` tag in your `<head>` seems to be the way to go...

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

...but there might be more that needs to be done. I set my `$locationProvider` to `html5Mode` too and got errors when I loaded my page.

```
myAngularModule.config($locationProvider =>
{
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false,
        rewriteLinks: false
    });
});
```

I also had to [configure my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting/22362994#22362994) for html5Mode.