# href causes unintended page reload with Angularjs and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, href

I am working on a project that uses Angularjs and Twitter Bootstrap.

Bootstrap uses # to toggle components such as popover, modal etc.
for example:

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I click on button with such href attribute, it causes full page reload, which means, everything in current page is lost.
**Is there a way to prevent this?**

some **extra** info:

when i hover on the button, the url is weird. for example, my current page's url is

```
localhost:8080/#/account
```

the button's href is

```
href="#myModal"
```

I expect to see url

```
localhost:8080/#/account#myModal
```

However, what I see is

```
localhost:8080/#myModal
```

I am not sure if this is related to my problem.

Thanks in advance!

***EDIT 1***

I have seen the other post that *Stewie* talked about. It explains html5mode and hashbang in angularjs, but it doesn't really solve my problem.

I tried putting html5mode, and it still reloads the page when i click on the button

Comment: why are you using an `<a>` when that has a clear and defined semantic role of internally navigating the page? It's not a link to a resource, why not just use a `<span>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [$location / switching between html5 and hashbang mode / link rewriting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting)

Comment: Have you looked at the `data-target` options ? That way you might be able to let angular choose the href.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The hashbang in Angular is used for [routing](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route). Look at the tutorial for a deeper insight into how it works [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07).

You should also take a look at [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Regular Boostrap wasn't built with Angular in mind, so there are few things that aren't in line with Angular. So the team decided to port Boostrap into Angular directives, giving you the ability to fully use Angular's `ng-` features (which you wouldn't be able to do easily with just regular Boostrap).

---

Due to the way routing works, I don't think you would be able to do what you want, and you shouldn't need to. Since you're using the `<a>` as a button, make it a regular button and add an `ng-click`:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="openDialog()">Open Dialog</button>
```

This is the Angular way (and how Angular UI Bootstrap works).

Lastly, in Angular, the `<a>` is a directive [docs here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aa), so if you want to prevent the default click, leave `href=""`:

```
<a href="" ng-click="model.$save()">Save</a>
```

Comment: It seems <a href="" ng-click=""> will prevent the ng-click operation in Android 2.3.x browser

Answer (score 27):

This is because of HTML link rewriting of Angular, explained [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).

To prevent rewriting of location, add `target=_self` to those bootstrap links.

So instead of `<a href="#myModal">` you need `<a href="#myModal" target="_self">`

Answer (score 6):

I solved:
Simply just change HREF attribute by the DATA-TARGET attribute.

```html
<div>
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
            <a data-target="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a data-target="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Tortor Porta Sit</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Duis mollis, est non commodo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was perhaps the easiest solution!

Comment: Thank you, you saved my time :)

Comment: Working great on Angular 7.

Answer (score 4):

There's a simpler solution here: [How to prevent redirecting <a href="#something"> in Angular Js1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995091/how-to-prevent-redirecting-a-href-something-in-angular-js1-2)

Just add `target="_self"` to your links

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues, full page reload vs just view switching.

Because Angular apps are SAPs, we only update whatever comes after hostname/#/.

I instantiate a SuperController, kind of the application level controller and like Carlos V said, you can use ng-click instead of href to update `$location.path()`.

Here's a fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/QnQ3m/)

Might not be the most optimal solution. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in ur js

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Just make sure you make a class for your 'a' otherwise you will do it to all a's.

Answer (score -9):

Go ahead & make the below change, of putting javascript:void(0) instead of #myModal for href. Use Javascript to trigger your modal opening, by putting a click event.

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="openModal()" role="button"...

    function openModal(){
      $("#myModal").moda();
    }
```