# How to prevent redirecting <a href="#something"> in Angular Js1.2

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, migration

I was using AngularJs-1.0.7 and Bootstrap in my application. Recently I migrated from AngularJs-1.0.7 to AngularJs-1.2. I am using Bootstrap's Accordions and Tabs.

Html code for Tab contains `<a href="#id_for_content">` as shown below.

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#firstTab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#secondTab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="firstTab">
      <p>Content for first tab.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="secondTab">
      <p>Content For second tab.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Angular's old versions, route change happens only if we give anchor tag like `<a href="#/firstTab">`. But AngularJs-1.2 redirects `<a href="#firstTab">`. It doesn't consider the `/` in between `#` and `firstTab`. Hence while clicking on Tab it redirects to `http://web_url/#/firstTab` . How to solve this issue?

---

#### My Solution

I found a solution for this issue. I wrote a directive for a tag. In that directive I checked for href attribute. If it matches prevent from its default behavior. Check the following code.

```
app.directive('a', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            if(attrs.href === '#firstTab'|| attrs.href === '#secondTab'){
                elem.on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            }
        }
   };
});
```

But the problem with this method is, I have to check each and every tab ids or accordion ids here. If I use dynamic Ids for them, its not possible to check in directive.

If you can find better solution, let us all know about it.

Comment: What if you use a `class` directive? I mean, a directive named `prevent-default` with `restrict: 'C'`, link function is the same without if part, then you can use it anywhere by adding class `"prevent-default"` to it... Like `<a href="..." class="prevent-default">...</a>` I guess mine is also a hacky solution but better than writing all id's. If you want I can modify code and send as answer.

Comment: `if(/^#/.test(attrs.href))` will work for all links beginning with a `#`.

Comment: Try adding `target="_self"` it generally disabled the angular routing on links.

Comment: Take a lot at these native angular directives based on bootstrap http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 50):

Just add this to your links:

```
target="_self"
```

And you're ready ;)

Comment: didn't work for me  <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_self">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

Comment: Your `href` is very generic. Try like `href="#something"` and I guess that you do have already this anchor in on element.

Answer (score 21):

try `data-target="#something"`, it works fine for me in both development and production environment.

Comment: Oh man this is great! Now i don't have to use angular-strap or angular-ui just for the modal and this is way easier.

Answer (score 11):

I would just like to let you know that there is another solution to solve this issue (without defining function in controllers).

You can create a directive that will prevent default browser's behaviour (which is actually changing URL):

```
var PreventDefault = function () {

    var linkFn = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).on("click", function (event){
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linkFn
    }
};
```

and then just add the directive to each `a` element responsible for toggling a tab like this:

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#firstTab" prevent-default data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#secondTab" prevent-default data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="firstTab">
      <p>Content for first tab.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="secondTab">
      <p>Content For second tab.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

In general you can define functions on the prototype of all scopes by using the rootscope. Add ng-click on your anchor tags and **pass the $event** to the rootscope handlers. Angular can send the originating event as well with ng-click:

```
<a ng-click="tabclick($event)">
```

in a run block of your module you can then set a tabClick function on $rootScope

```
$rootScope.tabclick = function ($event) { $event.preventDefault(); }
```

This will work for any scopes and you won't have to check against specific element ids.

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stto3703/wQe6P/

Cheers

Comment: I used `target="_self"` instead of defining a function and calling it.

Comment: You can also use `<a href="#" ng-click="tabclick(); $event.preventDefault();">` to avoid passing event into every function processing the click

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-click to call a function in your JS. In that function, use the event's `preventDefault` method, and use `$location`'s `hash` method to change the hash in your URL.

Comment: This is not a good solution. Here I need to define that function in all controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this problem for a while now too, and I only just stumbled across this question (and your own answer).  It turns out that you are almost correct with your solution, just a slight modification makes it work as you'd like.

In addition to the issue you were having with tabs, I was also encountering this problem with dropdown links -- they were navigating away from the current page when clicked, instead of dropping down the menu -- and in fact, this problem is present on any link that was designed to toggle something, i.e. with the data-toggle attribute set.

So, a slight modification to your code to check for the presence of the 'toggle' attribute solves it for me:

```
app.directive('a', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            if(attrs.toggle){
                elem.on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            }
        }
   };
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution in your question does work, but to prevent having to check for each anchor's id, change

```
if (attrs.href === '#firstTab'|| attrs.href === '#secondTab')
```

to

```
if (attrs.href && attrs.href.indexOf('#') > -1)
```

Directive:

```
.directive('a', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            if (attrs.href && attrs.href.indexOf('#') > -1) {
                elem.on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            }
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

credits to 
https://prerender.io/js-seo/angularjs-seo-get-your-site-indexed-and-to-the-top-of-the-search-results/

My solution:
 - inside app.js try adding "$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');"

```
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('menu', {
        url: '/',
        cache: false,
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'static/www/templates/menu.html'
    })
    .state('menu.main_page', {
    url: 'app/main',
    cache: false,
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'static/www/templates/mainpage.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
        }
    }
    })
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
        var $state = $injector.get('$state');
        $state.go('menu.mainpage');
    });
   }])
```

- inside index.html try adding

  `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`

and as **Marcel** said above

```
.directive('a', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        if (attrs.href && attrs.href.indexOf('#') > -1) {
            elem.on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    }
};
})
```

that's all! works for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't success with previous answers, you could try use $timeout... In this case I have used AngularUI tabs...

```
vm.removeUserTab = function (user) {
    $timeout(function () {
        vm.activeTab = 0;
        var index = vm.userTabs.indexOf(user);
        vm.userTabs.splice(index, 1);
    });
};
```