# Making ul act like select

Tags: jquery, html-lists, dropdown

I have to make ul act like a dropdown. I'm trying with the following code. If I select a value from ul, it writes in `selected_category` but if I want to change the selected value from ul, I can't. Where I am wrong?

```js
$(function() {
 $( document.body ).on( 'click', '.category_dropdown li', function( event ) {
 
   var $target = $( event.currentTarget );
 

   $target.closest( '.btn-group' )
      .find( '#selected_category' ).text( $target.text() )
         .end()
      .children( '.category_dropdown' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );
 
   return false;
 
});



});
```

```html
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                   <span id="selected_category"></span>
                    <span class="caret" id="caret_black"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu category_dropdown">
                    <li class="category_select" >
                        <a href="#">
                             Choose
                        </a>
                     </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#"
                            Value 1
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Value 2
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: did you try select from position instead value?

Comment: What do you mean? Could you give some example?

Comment: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/convert-a-list-into-a-select-dropdown-using-jquery.html

Comment: I don't want to change how it looks. I want to be ul but when I click on li, to append to selected_category and also links don't work in li. I tried with: ` <a href="<?php echo URL::base();?>images/create/value1" >
                            <span class="">value1</span>
                            </a>`

Comment: you want to set selected some value like value 2 right?

Comment: I want when use clicks on some of the values of ul, to goes to the link in ul and in span with id="selected_category" text to be value from selected li.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995091/how-to-prevent-redirecting-a-href-something-in-angular-js1-2

Comment: So, I can use Angular to show value of li and at the same time to redirect to my link, is this right? Thanks!

Comment: exactly i dont follow that link but i think that should be work in your requirement.