# Angularjs binding array splice

Tags: arrays, angularjs, binding, splice

I have an issue with splicing an array:

I m displaying my array like this :

```
Email:<input type="text" ng-model="newcontact"/>
    <button ng-click="add(newcontact)">Add</button>
    <h2>Contacts</h2>

  <ul id="todo-list">
    <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">

            <a href="#">{{contact.libelle}}</a>
            <a href="#" ng-click="del($index)">del</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

My controller is :

```
angular.module('angulartestApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$log) {
    var $scope.contacts = [{libelle:'test'},{libelle:'test2'}];

    $scope.add = function(newcontact) {
        $scope.contacts.push({libelle:newcontact});
        $scope.newcontact = '';
    };

    $scope.del = function (idx){
        $scope.contacts.splice(idx, 1);
        for (var i=0;i<$scope.contacts.length;i++)
        {
            $log.info($scope.contacts[i].libelle+',');
        }

    };

  });
```

If I add two items ('a' and 'b'), my view displays the good items in my list ('test', 'test2', 'a','b').

If I delete the 'a' item, my view displays only the two initial items of my list ('test', 'test2').
But in the console everything is good, 'test', 'test2' and 'b' gets well displayed.

I don't understand why. If someone can show me the good way to do it...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is the page being reloaded when you click the del link? Try using a button instead of  to verify. This may also help:

[href causes unintended page reload with Angularjs and Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251864/href-causes-unintended-page-reload-with-angularjs-and-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: my page is not being reloaded

Comment: Actually, I re checked, my windows seems to be reloaded when it leaves the del() function, not when exiting the add() function.

Comment: Use a button for delete rather than a link.