# html5Mode with base tag does not work on refresh

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

[AngularJS - html5Mode - Cannot GET /login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993766/angularjs-html5mode-cannot-get-login)

So I have seen this post and my problem is very similar. I have used base tag to get my relative urls to work. And I have $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); in my application. Everything seems to work fine to keep /#/ urls out of the application, but when the user refreshes the browser it says page not found. The url it is going to is where my router should be pointing to:

```
$routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/coverPage.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/coverPage', {
        templateUrl: 'views/coverPage.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
```

This is just an example of my router page. Again, this works when I link through a button, but when I load the url: http://www.someurl.com/somepath/coverPage it says page not found.

Answer (score 0):

If it works fine, when navigating from a link but get a page not found when you refresh it appears to be a server side issue.

Be sure to acutally load the right angular app from the server at the specified url. You need a kind of wildcard url matching for the server side route. But without knowing more details of your application I can only guess.

Comment: well I built it using yeoman, thus the tag for them. I probably should have gone into greater detail about that though. I am using yeoman angular, whole thing builds great, except for this refresh issue. It happens on my local machine with grunt serve and when I put it on our server, which is why I thought it was more of an angular issue. But I have not verified that.

Comment: http://jjt.io/2013/11/16/angular-html5mode-using-yeoman-generator-angular/

This site gave me all the answers I need.