# cannot get error using angularjs with express.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've a file of index.html that has

```
     <ui-view></ui-view>
```

in the body and below is my route.js :

```
var app = angular.module('dashboard', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
            .state("home", {
                url: "/",
                template:"<h1>home</h1>"
            })
            .state("dashboard", {
                url: "/dashboard",
                templateUrl: "templates/dashboard.html",
                controller: "controllers/dashboardCtrl"
            })           
}]);
```

but I get error of Cannot GET /dashboard I wonder why. I did have a folder called templates and has a dashboard.html in it.

Comment: show me the Url that how your calling in browser

Comment: Add your server-side code, please. Do you serving files from "template" folder in the root?

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov I have this 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'templates')));

Comment: @SaEChowdary localhost:3000/dashboard

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993766/angularjs-html5mode-cannot-get-login check out this link may help you

Comment: @SaEChowdary thanks but can u take a look at my repo? https://github.com/eldyvoon/cart-aff

Comment: when I do `router.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile('/public/templates/index.html');
});` it says the file not exisit?!