# Need to remove hash before url params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
$location.url('?filterBy='+web.websiteId);
```

In this code add params after my url but it also add # before ?filterBy=

Like

```
www.asasa.com/asas#?filterBy=1
```

but i need like this

```
www.asasa.com/asas?filterBy=1
```

I am using angularjs 1.2.17

Comment: Why are you doing `?` anyway?

Comment: I am using ? because of need to add params after my url (Not for this code).So i can't remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you require some data on other state/controller. First of all this is a traditional method. The more proper way would be to RESTful approach when setting up the routes, like

```
.when('/asas', ...)
.when('/asas/:filterBy', ...)
```

and when changing the location you can do

```
$location.path( "/asas" );
$location.path( "/asas/1" );
```

Comment: Is there no option to remove hash before params ?

Comment: You can use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) in order to avoid # in your urls. This line need to be in your app config function

Comment: var app = angular.module('onlinedeals', []);
app.controller('onlineCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $window,$location) { 
  $http({method: 'GET', url: '/asasa/dfdfd/asa'}).success(function(data) {       
      $scope.website = data.websites;
      $scope.onlinedata = data.coupons; This is my app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214835/angularjs-how-to-enable-locationprovider-html5mode-with-deeplinking

Comment: the question has a code in which there is a section app.config you can make use of that

Comment: When i add app.config(function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}); then it working find but in ie8 it redirect to home page

Comment: I think there is a problem with IE<9 with HTML 5 there is good documentation how to enable it in angular and otherwise http://www.paulund.co.uk/turn-on-html5-in-ie8-or-lower