# Angular-routing, direct URL navigation

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have an angular app defined on my `index.html` file.
Using angular-routing i am routing a link named `/erez` to load a view with a template. It's working inside the app - when I click the link to `/erez` from the navbar on `index.html` it works perfectly.
But when I go directly to my.site.com/erez on the address bar, it gives `404`. I understand why that is, having no server-side code, but is there a pure angular way of achieving direct urls?
my routing code:

```
var app = angular.module('labApp', ['ngRoute', 'angular.filter']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'index.html',
            controller: 'mainCtrl'
        }).
        when('/erez', {
            templateUrl: 'erez2.html',
            controller: 'erezCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find lots of useful information from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214835/angularjs-how-to-enable-locationprovider-html5mode-with-deeplinking):

So either you need this base url tag inside the  tag:

```
<base href="/" />
```

But be aware, this base tag may break the relative links in your code. Alternatively you can use:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No luck. I managed to solve with some editing to .htaccess, which is okay for now but it's not elegant.

Now I have a problem that base href breaks my carousel on the landing page. Any tips?

Comment: Like said in the answer, base tag breaks relative path, I presume the carousel is not working due to images can not be found, you can inspect the broken link and see the current broken path and modify it to the correct ones.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it should work now.

```
var app = angular.module('labApp', ['ngRoute', 'angular.filter']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'index.html',
                controller: 'mainCtrl'
            }).
            when('/erez', {
                templateUrl: 'erez2.html',
                controller: 'erezCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });
    });
```