# Angular JS UI-Route Navigation

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a simple routing using UI-Route in Angular,but when I'm  typing url in browser with `#` like this `http://localhost:8080/#/stateone` it adds some weird symbols to it like this `http://localhost:8080/#!#%2Fstateone`. Can anybody explain me what`s wrong with that?

Here`s my code in app.js file :

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ["ngMaterial", "ui.router"])
    .config(function($mdThemingProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('teal')
    .accentPalette('orange');

    $stateProvider
        .state('stateone' , {
        url: '/stateone',
        template: '<h1>State One</h1>'
    })

    .state('statetwo', {
        url: '/statetwo',
        template: '<h1>State Two</h1>'
    });
});
```

Template`s file code:

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

Comment: your hash-bang is `#!`, so by introducing `#/stateone` it makes it `#!#/stateone` which is URL-encoded into `#!#%2Fstateone`

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your urls in AngularJS and avoid the hash-bang from your overall app by enabling html5mode mode by adding this simple line in your config block of app.js

> $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Reference link: [AngularJS: how to enable $locationProvider.html5Mode with deeplinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214835/angularjs-how-to-enable-locationprovider-html5mode-with-deeplinking)

Answer (score 0):

This problem could appear with the migration from version 1.5 to 1.6...

One of the most notable changes are:

Changing the default $location hash-prefix to '!', as the previous empty string default was unconventional and confusing.

> the default hash-prefix used for $location hash-bang URLs has changed
>   from the empty string ('') to the bang ('!'). If your application does
>   not use HTML5 mode or is being run on browsers that do not support
>   HTML5 mode, and you have not specified your own hash-prefix then
>   client side URLs will now contain a ! prefix. For example, rather than
>   mydomain.com/#/a/b/c the URL will become mydomain.com/#!/a/b/c.

If you actually want to have no hash-prefix, then you can restore the previous behavior by adding a configuration block to you application:

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
 $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

[Details](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52)