# Ionic Angular 1: ui-sref ui-router garbled url on ion-tab: "/#!/!/" and "/#!#%2F"

Tags: angular, url, ionic-framework, location, ui-sref

I had working tab navigation and I upgraded my packages.

Now when trying to navigate to a tab the urls are getting garbled up.

If my url is: `/#!/messages`, and I click on the Contacts tab, instead of going to `/#!/contacts`, the url becomes: `/#!/!/contacts`.

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top">
    <ion-tab title="Contacts" ui-sref="tab.contacts"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Messages" ui-sref="tab.messages"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

I feel I've got a version problem with ionic and angular but I don't know where to start figuring this out.

Here's the basic routing (Typescript):

```
$stateProvider
    .state('tab', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/includes/tab_bar.html"
    })
    .state('tab.contacts', {
        url: '/contacts',
        views: {
            'contacts': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/contacts.html',
                controller: 'ContactsController',
                controllerAs: '$ctrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('tab.messages', {
        url: '/messages',
        views: {
            'account': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/messages.html',
                controller: 'MessagesController',
                controllerAs: '$ctrl'
            }
        }
    })
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(() => '/messages');
```

Tab navigation was working acceptably until I upgraded JavaScript modules up to the latest.

I'm sure somebody with nostalgia for the *ancient* version 1 has a memory of such problems?

I don't want to supplant this nice clean method with `href` or `$state.go`.  The `ui-sref` seems like best practice.  So I want resolve the problem, not hack a solution.

Thanks Much!

Comment: Additional Information:  If I manually type in the urls correctly, I can navigate to the tabs.  And then once I do that, clicking on the tabs works correctly?  Totally unclear what's going on in the middle of ui-router here.  Caching?

Comment: Any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214835/angularjs-how-to-enable-locationprovider-html5mode-with-deeplinking
Maybe look at $location / switching between html5 and hashbang mode / link rewriting on there too.