# angularjs path change not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have a navbar area that lives in my index.html file, the rest of the content is in partials inside a ng-view. Within the navbar it displays the user's username and has a logout link. Clicking the link logs out the user and I'd like to redirect them back to the login page.

Here's my logout method in my navBar controller:

```
 $scope.logOut = function () {
    console.log('logging out');
    StackmobService.logout();
    $location.path('/logout');
    $scope.currentUser='';
};
```

My router is as follows:

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/register', {templateUrl: 'partials/register.html',   controller: 'LoginCtrl'}).
    when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',   controller: 'LoginCtrl'}).
    when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',   controller: 'LoginCtrl'}).
    when('/events', {templateUrl: 'partials/events.html',   controller: 'EventCtrl'}).
    when('/logout', {templateUrl: 'partials/register.html',   controller: 'LoginCtrl'}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
```

Here's the body piece of my index.html file:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="navbar" ng-controller="NavBarCtrl">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">spreevent</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p class="navbar-text pull-right" ng-show="currentUser.username">
            Welcome {{currentUser.username}}
            <a href="#"  ng-click="logOut()">Logout</a>
        </p>

    </div>

    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

Any idea why its not changing?

Comment: Probably a typo, but just in case you didn't notice... in logOut() you set the path to `/logout` instead of `/login`.

Comment: Well I should update my router to go to login.html instead of register.html for /logout. But if you look at my router, right now the /logout path should redirect to register.html and its not even doing that. its not redirecting at all.

Comment: Okay, my mistake.  Is 'logging out' being logged to the console?

Comment: yep, it is. its logging out the user.

Comment: Is it only the logout route that isn't working?

Comment: Its not the logout route thats the issue. For example I changed the $location.path after logout to go to login and it still didn't work. Its how/where I'm calling it after logout that's the issue. Is it because its being called from the index.html instead of inside a ng-view?

Comment: That shouldn't matter.  Can you set up a plunker or a fiddle?

Comment: So I gave the plunkr a shot but I don't think you can get it to work with routing since its not working in html5 hashbang mode. It always hits the 'otherwise' route: http://plnkr.co/edit/lWPtxY0cXKEY90BCmUE5

Comment: Using `<a href="" ng-click="logOut()">Logout</a>` worked in the plunker, instead of `<a href="#" ...`.  Does that solve your problem?  If not what mode are you using in your app, HTML5, hashbang, or hashbang in HTML5 (see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/16678065/215945)?

Comment: removing the # solved it!  I'll have to read up on the differences in that link, thanks for that, if you add this as an answer ill mark it fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, use

```
<a href="" ng-click="logOut()">Logout</a>
```

rather than

```
<a href="#" ....
```