# IIS URL rewrite module with angularJS does not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a single page webapp where any request that begins with request for e.g. `http://localhost/appname/request*` , the home page is sent back to the client using IIS URL rewrite module.

When Angular receives the webpage, it sees the route. I need to make sure Angular picksup up the routeParams.

Client request : `http://localhost/appname/request/param1/param2`

```
$routeProvider.when('/request/:param1/:param2',{
    templateUrl : 'app/views/myView.html',
    controller : 'MyCtrl',
    caseInsensitiveMatch : true
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' , caseInsensitiveMatch : true });     

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

The controller listens to `$routeChangeSuccess`.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',function(event,routeData,$timeout,$rootScope){
     //routeData.pathParams are blank    
    });    
});
```

Also the URL changes to home page. I.e. I am redirected to `http://localhost/appname`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the route params but the correct way to do this is by injecting $routeParams into the controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope, $routeParams){
    if($routeParams.param1){
        alert('SUPER FLY!');
    }

});
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: If you are tryinng to use html 5 mode, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting

Comment: Thanks. The reason I was redirected was because of the `otherwise` rule. I haven't really made any changes but its working now. Also I didn't have to pass `$routeParams` along with `$scope`. I used `$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, routeData){});` inside my `Myctrl`.