# angularjs $location.hash makes ##, but i need #

Tags: url, angularjs

AngularJS 1.2.0 (but lower versions have the same problem)

I have a web app with some widgets and want to save their state into URL.
I do this now with `$location.hash('param1=1&param2=678')` command. But I get url like: `domain.com/##param1=1&param2=678`
It works ok, I can restore state of my app. One problem I have with that is when someone click such a link in, for example, mail app, their browser encodes one of hashes with /23 and so my app goes wrong. How can i solve this? Thanks

Here is plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/VVjEUzROou6hu8B8sURa?p=preview
You need open it in new window to able to test hashes

Comment: maybe because href="#" is in your anchor tag? try with href="javascript:" instead.

Comment: I just noticed that same behaviour (double hash) is happening in the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll), weird

Answer (score 8):

for standard hash locations in angular, you use

```
location.path("myappstate/1");
```

as angular is set up to think of first hash state as the primary url or path for the app. The location.hash() setups a secondary hash on the primary hash state (path)

Comment: It's actually `location.hash = 'myhash';`

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best answer, but you could try to inject $locationProvider and set:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

That way angular runs in HTML5 mode and it does not use hashbangs. I recommend [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$location.search("key", "value")
```

instead.
If you have complex state you can even directly supply an object to the search method:

```
$location.search({foo: bar, baz: duh});
```

Comment: I used .search() for serialization before, but gone to hash, because it is better to parse strings myself. I still didnt solve the problem. If someone want to see in in action: http://infolek.ru