# AngularJS - $routeProvider.when - Without anchor to my url

Tags: angularjs

i have this code for my routes. Everything works fine with these links except one link... The link without anchor

```
myapp.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/library2/test1.html',
            controller: 'libraryController'
        }).
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: '/library2/test0.html',
            controller: 'libraryController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });

}]);
```

Works fine: /user/7/library2/#/home

Works fine: /user/7/library2/#/else

Works fine: /user/7/library2/#

Works BAD:  /user/7/library2/

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: What does 'Works BAD' mean? loads `/home` or `/`? Crashes angular?

Comment: It doesn't load the case i want. Without crashing... it just ignore $routeProvider. Why it doesn't load the root view? "/"

Comment: Any errors in console ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the hashbang concept in angular, please give a read below

[$location / switching between html5 and hashbang mode / link rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting)