# How can I get the full url of the current ui-router state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router for AngularJS; I'm handling the `'$stateChangeSuccess'` event, and trying to get the full path (after '#') for the current state.  `$location.hash()` returns an empty string and `$state.url` returns only the portion of the path that applies to the nested state.

My full path `#/a/b`

```
$state.url == "/b"
$locadtion.hash() == ""
```

How can I get `#/a/b` or `/a/b`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always use:

```
window.location
```

or:

```
window.location.hash
```

(if that's what you want).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried $location.url()?  <strike>That should include the hash.</strike> Actually, my test reveals that it doesn't grab the hash.

[$location docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

As an aside, you may want to look into setting html5Mode in $locationProvider.

Comment: Does html5Mode help with the solution, or is it just a better practice?  If so, what's the advantage?

Comment: [This stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16678065/1435916) answer explains what it does and why it may matter better than I could.

Comment: To better answer your question, the reason I used it was to get rid of the # appearing in the url bar.

Answer (score 1):

You should listen to the `$locationChangeSuccess` event.

There you can use `$location.path()` or `window.location.hash` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

try concatenating the URI parts together

window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + window.location.hash

PS: doesn't work on Firefox :(