# Google Friendlier Angular URLs?

Tags: angularjs, seo, routes

I'm making an entire site using angular. Using routes the urls come out to www.mysite.com/#/mypage. I'd like this to change to www.mysite.com/mypage without navigating away from the page and do screenshots for google bots. How can I do this with angular?

Comment: Maybe you can try html5mode http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

Comment: This post will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting

Comment: And if you're looking for a complete SEO solution, go for this

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow [Google rules](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) regarding SPA crawling.

1) Enable [Angular HTML5 mode](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location) and hashbang prefix with :

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

So you will have standard urls (www.mysite.com/mypage) on modern browser for your users, and hashbangs urls (www.mysite.com/#!/mypage) for old browsers and crawlers.

2) Add `<meta name="fragment" content="!" />` to your head

3) For each angular pretty url ( #!/mypage/key=value) your server also need to serve ugly urls (#!/mypage?_escaped_fragment_=key=value) with an HTML snapshot. You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for this.

And you are done, but for best results also implement [canonical urls](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066).