# How to make Angular router (or ui-router) accept routes like `#foo` instead of redirecting to `#/foo`?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

## Terminology

- `#foo`: slashless scheme
- `#/foo`: slashy scheme

## Background

There are certain legacy parts of the application which use (and rely on) the slashless scheme. I would like to introduce Angular routing (probably with ui-router) in a non-destructive way, such that doesn't interfere with the legacy routing so that part of the application could be gracefully phased out over time. Once that happens the all-angular app could switch to the slashy scheme all at once.

## So far

I tried setting `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('')` to an empty string, but it seems you can only set the string between `#` and `/`, so that didn't work.

## Options

It seems I can either

- rewrite legacy parts of the app, or
- rewrite Angular's $locationProvider.hashPrefix to include `'/'` by default. Therefore setting it to `''` would become meaningful.

Both of these options seem very time-consuming.

Do you know about a better way to make Angular recognize the slashless scheme?

Comment: If I get your question correctly, you should use the HTML routing mode. Here is a similar reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting

Answer (score 1):

You can try using redirects!

With `ui-router`:

```
app.config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
  // when there is an 'old' route, redirect to new one
  $urlRouterProvider.when('foo', '/foo');

  // You can also use regex for the match parameter
  $urlRouterProvider.when(/(\w+)/i, '/$1'); // UNTESTED!!!!!!
})
```

Reference about [ui-router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)

I'm sorry but hashtags are quite hard to test in plunkers/fiddles, so i'm not providing one for now...

Comment: Hmm, doesn't this do the opposite of what my question says? I'd like `#foo` **NOT** to redirect to `#/foo`.