# Issues with Angular Routing with HTML5

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angular-routing

I have an Angular app that's loading in content from an API through a Python (Django) proxy. The Angular app sits on a single Django template and fetches an object every time the user interacts with a control.

I need the URL to reflect this new object every time it changes.

For example:

`http://domain.com/foo/bar/apples` would bring up the apples object

`http://domain.com/foo/bar/oranges` would bring up the oranges object

I looked into [$location](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/docs/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) which seems to do the trick, but I'm having trouble getting non-html5 browsers to do what I want.

When set `$locationProvider` to HTML5 mode everything is great on modern browsers

HTML5

`/foo/bar/apples` becomes `/foo/bar/oranges/` GREAT!

However, on Non-HTML5

`/foo/bar/apples` becomes `/#!/foo/bar/oranges/` Not-Great!

Since it looks like legacy browsers require a hashbang, I'd like to move that to the latter part of the url, like so `/foo/bar/#!/oranges/`

If I set `$location.html5Mode` to `false`, the hashbang appears on both modern and legacy browsers (`/#!/foo/bar/oranges/`), but I'd like modern browsers to have non-hashbang url

Thoughts?

I'm using Angular 1.2.9

My Config:

```
myApp.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

On slug change, I'm calling the `$locationProvider` like so:

`$location.path('foo/bar/' + slug);`

Comment: wouldn't this be more related to the server side rewrite configuration and possibly the base url set in the HTML than angular itself

Comment: Well, it looks like Angular is rewriting the entire URL and reloading the page. I have created a rewrite on the server to support the hash being near the right side of the url, `/foo/bar/#/slug` but `/#/foo/bar/slug/` is something angular is doing.

Comment: You are going to have issues on the server anyway, because the hash fragment never get's sent to the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [$location / switching between html5 and hashbang mode / link rewriting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting)