# Cannot GET / page

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I am trying to use [grunt contrib connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) for local development and testing of an angular app.

the gruntfile is configured like so:

```
connect: {
    server: {
        options: {
            open: true,
            keepalive: true, 
            hostname: 'localhost',
            port: 8080
        }
    }
}
```

and the task

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', [
    'connect:server'
]);
```

`grunt serve` opens the browser with the file listing of the root directory. Clicking on the `dist` directory launches the app. Everything is fine until here: it's possible to change page from the app menu, but… direct access or reload of any of these pages, gives `Cannot GET /dist/page`… It's necessary to go back to `localhost:8080/dist' to make it work again…

What could I do to make this work?

Comment: Is the `$locationProvider` being set to use HTML5 mode? Would look like `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`. If so, when in the app, the location URL is being modified as the route changes but the browser is not actually requesting that new URL from the server. On reload, the browser *is* asking for that URL and the server has no matching resource for it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes `html5Mode`is `true`. Is there anything I can do to make it work? (like on the remote server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24384293/2112538), using grunt [connect-modrewrite](https://github.com/tinganho/connect-modrewrite)

the grunt task is now:

```
server: {
    options: {
        port: 9000,
        livereload: 35729,
        hostname: 'localhost',
        open: true,
        middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
                        modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']),
                        connect.static('dist')
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you add the **base** option to specify the 'dist' directory as the root for the Connect server:

```
connect: {
    server: {
        options: {
            open: true,
            keepalive: true, 
            hostname: 'localhost',
            port: 8080,
            base: 'dist'
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, it will at least make the routes less confusing.