# AngularJS $routeProviders does not work when I type in the address bar

Tags: angularjs, url, routes

**EDIT :** I forgot to say that I used Yeoman with generator-angular (Grunt, Bower, Angular, angular-route to generate my files.

I then, used **Grunt Serve.**

My routes on angularJS only works when I click on my menu.
When I type the url in the address bar (URL bar), it says

```
Cannot GET /about
```

Btw, I used this following tutorial to remove the hashtag from url:
https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

and it works fine when I click on the menu.

My index.html menu :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <base href="/">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    ...
    <ul class="pure-menu-list">
        <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected"><a href="/about" class="pure-menu-link">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="/work" class="pure-menu-link">WORK</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="/blog" class="pure-menu-link">BLOG</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="/contact" class="pure-menu-link">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  ...
  </body
</html>
```

My routes app.js :

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        redirectTo: '/about'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'about'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
      //check browser support
      if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
        // if you don't wish to set base URL then use this
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true
        });
      }
    }]);
```

### SOLUTION

First, you need to install connect-modrewrite via npm :

```
npm install --save-dev connect-modrewrite
```

Then make sure you have the following declared at the top of your Gruntfile.js:

```
var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');
```

Final step: add this in your middleware in your Gruntfile.js

```
modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']),
```

Here the full code:

```
livereload: {
    options: {
        open: true,
        middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
                modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']),
                connect.static('.tmp'),
                connect().use(
                    '/bower_components',
                    connect.static('./bower_components')
                ),
                connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
        }
    }
},
```

Thanks to Kryx
[AngularJS html5Mode using Grunt connect. grunt 0.4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283653/angularjs-html5mode-using-grunt-connect-grunt-0-4-5)

Comment: did you configure server for the virtual directories being used? Sounds like a server issue

Comment: Are you putting in the appropriate # ?

Comment: I forgot to say that I used Yeoman with generator-angular so I used Grunt Serve.

Comment: Where should I put the #?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLUTION

First, you need to install connect-modrewrite via npm :

```
npm install --save-dev connect-modrewrite
```

Then make sure you have the following declared at the top of your Gruntfile.js:

```
var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');
```

Final step: add this in your middleware in your Gruntfile.js

```
modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']),
```

Here the full code:

```
livereload: {
    options: {
        open: true,
        middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
                modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']),
                connect.static('.tmp'),
                connect().use(
                    '/bower_components',
                    connect.static('./bower_components')
                ),
                connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
        }
    }
},
```

Thanks to Kryx
[AngularJS html5Mode using Grunt connect. grunt 0.4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283653/angularjs-html5mode-using-grunt-connect-grunt-0-4-5)