# Third party library not working with angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am using navgoco.js and angular js in an application and I have following html

```
    <div id="demo">
   <ul >
       <li ng-repeat ... >
          <a href="#"> ... </a>  
          ......
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

js code

```
$j("#demo1").navgoco({accordion: false});
```

It is supposed to do some expand-collapse of menus.

the problem is that navgoco events are not performing on clicking on anchor. It simply adds `#` to url. In the rendered html of anchor tag, anuglar is adding ng-binding that may be the problem. Please help.

Comment: Hello, i'm not sur but you can use this $locationProvider
  .html5Mode(true); for disable prefix of url [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting). Good luck

Comment: Please, share you solution, if you found any.

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove the `href="#"` from the `a` tag to prevent angularjs to intercept the event.

Also see: [$location guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) at "Html link rewriting" section.

Answer (score 0):

the <a> tag is a directive in angularjs. see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/a