# Set links to fallback to hashbang for older browsers

Tags: angularjs

I'm setting HTML5 mode on. And thus, links in template are written without hashbang like:

```
<a ng-href='/link/to/action'>Click here</a>
```

But problem is, older IE versions need the hashbang urls and I know that angularjs will fallback for IE to hashbang.
But I'm already forming the links according to HTML5. How to fallback my own links to hashbangs?

In other words,
I want my links in the template to reflect the mode (HTML5 or hashbang) type and set its href accordingly.

So, for older browsers, I want the link to be like this instead:

```
<a ng-href='/#/link/to/action'>Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

Add this to you `app.config` function, it will disable the html5 mode, and enable hash `#`

if you need `!` also then add this too

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

Ex:

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
         $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
         $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    })
```

**EDIT:** For checking html5 you can include the modernizer.js library, or use the code samples they provide

Here are some techniques you can use to find a browser supports Html5 or not

http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#geolocation

Ex:

```
if (Modernizr.geolocation) {     
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
} else {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
}
```

Comment: This is the default behaviour. I'm setting it to ON to enable it, I know. But I want it OFF for older browser versions along with the appropriate type of links in my template that point to the correct mode for every type of browser.

Comment: Here you have explanation of routing modes in Angular http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting

Comment: Check my edit, You can use modernizr.js for detecting html5 browser