# In routing for angularJS how to remove '#' in url?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, routes

I am stuck with routing AngularJS.
Can someone suggest how to remove '#' in url in routing for angularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use HTML5Mode

please find more explaination on this link
[HTMLMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting)

Answer (score 1):

for that you need to use:  HTML5 Mode

you can set it like below

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

you can read more about this [here](http://scotch.io/quick-tips/js/angular/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)