# Spring Boot and angularJS - Routing is not working in my demo project

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot

i am facing problem to implement the angular routing in one of my learning project, i am trying to create a very simple project for learning purpose and it seems i got stuck in the initial stage itself, please guide me what i am doing wrong here, below are the respective elements i have used in my project, index.html is the home page which works good , but somehow i am not able do achieve routing.

My goal : i want to create single page application , so i want view1, view2 should end up on index.html only and for that purpose i have used `<div data-ng-view=""></div>` in index.html.

note: i have not shared the spring elements (classes , maven pom , etc..) as i feel spring boot is working perfectly i am doing something wrong in the angularJS side.

any help will be greatly appreciable :)

### app.js

```
appDemo.controller("view1controller",function($scope){ });

appDemo.controller("view2controller",function($scope){ });

appDemo.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {$routeProvider.
                    when('/demo/view1', {templateUrl: 'view1.html',controller: 'view1controller'}).
                    when('/demo/view2', {templateUrl: 'view2.html',controller: 'view2controller'}).
                    otherwise({redirectTo: '/demo/view1'});
}]);
```

### index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html data-ng-app="demoApp">
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

<div class="form-group">
<div data-ng-controller="view1controller"><a href="/demo/view1">get view1</a></div>
<div data-ng-controller="view1controller" ><a href="/demo/view2">get view2</a></div>
<div data-ng-view=""></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

### HomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);    

        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String greeting(Map<String, Object> model) {

            return "index";
        }
    }
```

view1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>VIEW1</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

view2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>VIEW1</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you send your project layout and the web.xml + application context

Comment: What does "not working" mean? If you want a single page application then why do you have multiple pages?

Comment: Are you injecting ngRoute in your module declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Routes.java

```
@Controller
    static class Routes {

        @RequestMapping({
            "/bikes",
            "/milages",
            "/gallery",
            "/tracks",
            "/tracks/{id:\\w+}",
            "/location",
            "/about"
        })
        public String index() {
            return "forward:/index.html";
        }
```

js

```
.config(
                function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

                    $routeProvider.
                            when('/', {
                                templateUrl: '/partials/_index.html',
                                controller: 'IndexCtrl'
                            }).
                            when('/bikes', {
                                templateUrl: '/partials/_bikes.html',
                                controller: 'BikesCtrl'
                            }).
                            when('/milages', {
                                templateUrl: '/partials/_milages.html',
                                controller: 'MilagesCtrl'
                            }).
                            otherwise({
                                redirectTo: '/'
                            });
                }
```

This is a nice link with routing example
http://info.michael-simons.eu/2014/04/15/spring-boot-as-a-backend-for-angularjs/

Comment: added essential parts

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the similar problem before using Spring Boot and Angularjs.

So you have your code: `<a href="/demo/view1">get view1</a>` in the event you click on the tag, and the URL on the web browser displays something like http://localhost:8080/#!/demo/view1/ **NOTICE:** The **/#!/** that appears in the url means you are in *(Hashbang in HTML5 Mode)* or just *(Hashbang mode).* AngularJS **ngRoute**  routing operates in three modes:

1. Hashbang Mode
2. HTML5 Mode
3. Hashbang in HTML5

This answer provides great info on the modes. [Angularjs routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting)
...and for more on *Hashbang mode* look [here](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/urls-routing-and-partials/client-side-routing-with-hashbang-urls.html)

Be aware that you can configure the routing mode by using $locationProvider e.g.`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` for HTML5 config or `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');` for Hashbang (#!).

Depending on the mode you will need to adjust your URLs `<a href="/demo/view</a>"` like so...

- For Hashbang & Hashbang in HTML5 use `<a href="#!/demo/view1">`
- For HTML5 `<a href="/demo/view1">` should be fine, but you might need to specify the url base such as :

`<head> 
....
<base href="/myUrlBase"> 
....
</head>`

or disable in the

`$locationProvider.html5Mode({
       enabled: true,
       requireBase: false  //disabled attribute
});`

Finally, be aware of where your **templateUrl:** points to `{templateUrl: 'view1.html', controller: 'view1controller'})` and `{templateUrl: 'view2.html',controller: 'view2controller'})`
Where they are currently pointing in your code for a (Spring Boot default config) placing your **view1.html** and **view2.html** directly below the **static folder** should work such as:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is responsive.  But this is easy to try.  I am experimenting with angular and spring-boot as well.  What I did was use web-jars version of angular.  If you are using Spring-Boot is is hard to debug.  Spring-Jars seems to be the route people are taking if you are using maven and client side scripting.  Also, when I added the spring my script tags in my index I needed to load angular-min.js, angular-resource.min.js, and angular-load.min.js before I was able to get spring-boot to work.  Once all three modules were loaded then angular seemed to work like a champ in spring-boot.