# Angular JS IE9 Hashbang url rewriting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Quite an odd situation here.

So I have two routes: `/RouteA` (`/` also defaults to here)  and `/RouteB`

`/RouteA` actually uses client side routing while `/RouteB` does not if that matters.

When I try navigating to `/RouteB`, the URL is initially `/RouteB` which is correct.

Since IE9 doesn't support HTML5, Angular rewrites the url with a hashbang to `/#/RouteB`

When the rewriting occurs, it forces a browser refresh (can we stop this behavior?) which sends me right back to `/` (which is ultimately `/RouteA`.

Is there a way to prevent the browser from resending the request when the url is rewritten?

The base tag is currently `<base href="/"/>`.

I tried doing something like this which allows me to land on the page, but breaks the anchor tag in the main menu thats trying to send me back to `/RouteA`:

```
  if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
  else {
     window.location.hash = '/';       
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
  }
```

e.g. `/#/RouteB` becomes `/RouteB/#/`. Then clicking on a link back to `/RouteA`, the route ends up becoming `/RouteB/RouteA` which obviously breaks.

So I tried the solution from a similar question but it yielded the same results as above. [$location / switching between html5 and hashbang mode / link rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see what's the big problem with it reloading on first visit back to `/#/RouteB`. At some point it's going to have to go back to that anyway otherwise you'll end up with urls like `/RouteB/#/RouteA`. The hashbang is a workaround for browsers that don't support pushstate, it's not going to be as pretty as pushstate.

Comment: I could care less about the reload if it didn't redirect me back to `/RouteA`. 
The problem is that anything after the `#` is ignored when a page is refreshed. So refreshing `someSite.com/#/RouteB` is the same as going to `someSite.com` as everything after the `#` is ignored.

Comment: So, the problem is, if you link them directly to /RouteB it's rewriting to /RouteA? it should be taking you to /#/RouteB. If that's rendering RouteA instead, I'd like to see your routing.

Comment: something wrong in your routing design. Sounds like you are expecting a single page app to work on multiple server routes which doesn't make sense

Comment: Its two separate single page apps on two separate server routes.  Server side there is a specific route for `RouteA` and `RouteB` with the default route of `/` also leading to `RouteA`. `RouteA` is the default SPA that is hit when you navigate to this site. Hence why the refresh of `foo.com/#/RouteB` is sending me back to `RouteA`.  Unfortunately that behavior cannot change.

Comment: server-side all routes should go to /index.html, angular will handle the routing.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working. It isn't pretty, but since there is no client side routing happening in `/RouteB` so it is good enough.

Before the two different apps shared an angular module. Instead I created two different modules and had those depend on the previously shared module.

```
angular.module('sharedModule', ['dependancy1', ...]);

<!-- RouteA app -->
<div ng-app="sharedModule">...

<!-- RouteB app -->
<div ng-app="sharedModule">...
```

Became

```
angular.module('sharedModule', ['dependancy1', ...]);
angular.module('routeAModule', ['sharedModule']);
angular.module('routeBModule', ['sharedModule']);


<!-- RouteA app -->
<div ng-app="routeAModule">...

<!-- RouteB app -->
<div ng-app="routeBModule">...
```

Then in `routeBModule` I used the fix from this post: [$location / switching between html5 and hashbang mode / link rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting) that was also mentioned above in my question.

Now when navigating to `/RouteB` the route gets rewritten to `/RouteB#/` which wont reload `/` and dumping me back a different page.

There were two gotcha's with this solution.

1. Navigating to this page with a trailing `/` can mess up relative links. e.g.  `/RouteB#/` becomes `/RouteB/#/` so trying to link to `/NewRoute` would end up linking to `/RouteB/NewRoute`
2. Anchor tags on this page with a `href="#"` cause the page to refresh.

There are likely many improvements that can be made to this and if I make them ill try to remember to update this answer.

Also if anyone has a better solution please feel free to post it.

<3 IE9

Answer (score -1):

What do your links to the routes look like? I think you need a full path to any routes going outside your application. You might try something like:

```
<a href="RouteA">Route A</a>
<a href="/RouteB">Route B</a>
```