# $location is throwing TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have just started with angularjs and I am following one tutorial, but I keep getting this error in chrome console

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at trimEmptyHash (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:10564:13)
at $LocationProvider.$get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:11374:9)
at Object.invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:4185:17)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:4003:37
at getService (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:4144:39)
at Object.invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:4176:13)
at extend.instance (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:8454:21)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:7700:13
at forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:331:20)
at nodeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:7699:11)
```

Here is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="file:///home/chintan/anges/" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>angular tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myOpenRecipes" ng-controller="recipeCtrl">
        <h1>{{searchTerm}}</h1>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my main.js file

```
window.MyOpenRecipes = angular.module('myOpenRecipes', []);

MyOpenRecipes.config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

MyOpenRecipes.controller('recipeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.searchTerm = "Pasta"
}]);
```

If I remove $location, it works perfectly. What could be wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce .... your code works fine here  http://plnkr.co/edit/sv8OiDCm2UnClzNBzEna. Your `base` looks very suspicious though. Suspect you are working from local file not localhost web server

Comment: It works fine in plnkr but it breaks in both chrome and firefox

Comment: Use a local server not file protocol

Comment: Thank You, It is working now with local server

Comment: This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting

Comment: I had similar issue when my base tag was mis-configured.

Comment: @charlietfl, please provide an answer.