# UI Router not recognising URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I've set up my `$stateProvider` as follows:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider, $httpProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('localitySearch',{
        url: '/venues/in/:cityName/:localityName/:localityId/',
        templateUrl: 'static/partials/localitysearch.html',
        controller: 'localitySearchCtrl'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
});
```

When I try to hit:

`/venues/in/CityName/LocalityName/LocalityId/`, it redirects to home page.

The same code works if use regular `ngRoutes`. Is there something I've missed that's preventing url redirection?

Comment: did you try hitting after `/!/venues/in/CityName/LocalityName/LocalityId/`?

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava, I'm actually trying to use HTML5Mode so there's no `!` in my URLs.

Comment: check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting

Comment: Are you using any backend frameworks, such as Laravel or Ruby on Rails? That can sometimes cause routing issues. The best place to start is by checking that everything is working without HTML5Mode first.

Comment: @EdB I am using Django. Up till now, I was using native ng routes and that worked perfectly. I changed that to `ui-router` and this the only url thats giving me issues.

Comment: Hmm. So you have other URLs that work without issue? In that case, aside from the HTML5Mode thing, I can only really suggest that you try working with a much shorter URL (with perhaps just 1 parameter) to start with, and slowly work in more complexity. I recommend you read through the answers given on the page that @ArpitSrivastava mentioned. The hashbang thing in particular.

Answer (score 2):

The concept is working. There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sSJtkJDxkyCVD12CRhX9?p=preview).

So with this state definition *(almost the same as above)*:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider
  .state('localitySearch',{
    url: '/venues/in/:cityName/:localityName/:localityId/',
    templateUrl: 'static/partials/localitysearch.html',
    controller: 'localitySearchCtrl'
  })
  .state('home', {
    url: "/home",
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html',  
  })

$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true, requireBase: false}).hashPrefix('!');
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
```

These links will work:

```
// href
<a href="{{plnkr}}venues/in/cityName/localityName/localityId/">
// ui-sref
<a ui-sref="localitySearch({cityName:'Liberec', localityName:'Czech', localityId:'CZ'})"
```

NOTE: the `{{plnkr}}` is just a way how to know the generated url in the plunker:

```
.run(['$rootScope', 
  function ($rootScope,) {
    $rootScope.plnkr = document.location.pathname;
}])
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sSJtkJDxkyCVD12CRhX9?p=preview)

Comment: I was using `window.location.href` to change urls in some places where this was breaking. The moment I moved to `$state.go`, it all started function correctly. Strange behavior.