# AngularJS $routeProvider and "404 Not Found" status

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, angular-routing

I'm using in my app:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/index.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: '/views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .when('/user/list', {
        templateUrl: '/views/users/list.html',
        controller: 'userListController'
    }) 
    });
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

and in html there is `<base href="/">`. I'm using this app in google app engin. In `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /(user)/.*
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```

everything is ok with links that starts with `user`. But in login there is `404 Not Found`error. Any advise about solution would be appreciated.

Comment: I dont see where you are configuring your base href "/"...

Comment: @Dsafds base href might be what here?

Comment: Basically in simpler terms.... There is no .when() for the "/"  So it will absolutely give you a 404...

Comment: @Dsafds I have edited my question. Now I have a mainController for "/". But the error still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove $locationProvider.. it produces many conflicts as said here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

> Use the $locationProvider to configure how the application deep
>   linking paths are stored.

Next remove the argument $httpProvider, because in the code you provided you are not using the provider anywhere in your .config() function... Hope this helped.

**EDIT**
App.yalm i think should look more like this..

```
handlers:
- url: '/' 
    script: main.app
```

Can you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191398/gae-app-yaml-routing-with-flask-restless) question to get a better understanding? Hope this helped!

Comment: I think it is an issue from app.yaml configs. Because there is the same problem with removing $locationProvider and $httpProvider

Comment: No Problem @TheNone any time... (Dont ask me how i responded this fast im a ninga :P)