# Angular hashtag changing file path

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create 2 separate applications within one site using AngularJS, and I'm trying to figure out how the RouteConfig interacts with the hashtag angular adds to the url.

Basically,
I enter `[sitename]/App1`
and this is changed to `[sitename]/App1#/` by angular, and everything works fine.

However if I enter `[sitename]/App1/` this is changed to `[sitename]/App1/#/` and everything breaks because it starts looking for html files under `http://[sitename]/App1/Views/Angular/[file.html]` instead of `http://[sitename]/Views/Angular/[file.html]` where they are located.

Why does this happen? Why does that extra slash added in there cause angular to change the path it looks for files?

Edit: Routing is as follows,

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Can you show how your routes are configured?

Comment: I was talking about the angular route config

Comment: take a read through of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16678065/3696076) in regards to `html5Mode`