# Redirect url (e.g. website.com/username) in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular website with the user profile (dynamic) on the following url:

```
http://website.com/#!/market/profile/username
```

where `username` is a dynamic variable.

How can I setup my website, such that going to:

```
http://website.com/username
```

will redirect to the appropriate url?

Note also that I want to remove the hashbang prefix #

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate? I am using ui.router but the initial state is home

Answer (score 1):

Here try this:

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
       when('/:username', {
       templateUrl: 'templates/users/show_user.html',
       controller: 'UsersController'
  });
}]);
```

This should be a good reference for it [here](https://sites.google.com/site/jeff00coder00seattle/home/general-programming-knowledge/angularjs/angularjs--howtopassparametersinrouteurls)

Comment: Sounds good, but doesnt that redorect website.com/#/:username instead of website.com/username

Comment: If you still having an issue, you can use this you just need to switch out of hashbang mode.  here is a link to where that can be done  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16678065/1938988 please mark your question as complete if this satisfies what you need to do.