# Why is my angular js app adding characters to the url?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

The url I enter is http://localhost:8080/app/#/intro
but it turns into http://localhost:8080/app/#!/intro#%2Fintro

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Looks like a router thing (without seeing any other code).

Comment: do you have htm5mode enabled?

Comment: I don't have html5mode enabled.

Comment: answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41121698/704133

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it has to do with angular updating to 1.6.0 where they changed the hash # to a hashbang #! syntax by default. If the app is loaded with a hash only url it adds that weirdness. The issue is gone if I just visit the #! version of the url directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the Html5Mode,

Route Configuration:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/path', {
    templateUrl: 'path.html',
  });
$locationProvider
  .html5Mode(true);
```

In your HTML set the base

```
<head>
 <base href="/"/>
</head>
```

In this mode you can use links without the # in HTML files

```
<a href="/path">link</a>
```

Original post here [$location / switching between html5 and hashbang mode / link rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting/16678065#16678065)