# Angular Routing ngRoute fails to pull my other HTML files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

So after reading here and there on MEAN, I decided to make my first MEAN application which is pretty small, all seems to work except the routeing to make my app a one-page app. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
 app.config(function($routeProvider){
   $routeProvider
     .when('/', {
       templateUrl: 'main.html',
       controller: 'mainController'
     })
     .when('/login', {
       templateUrl: 'login.html',
       controller: 'authController'
     })
     .when('/register', {
       templateUrl: 'register.html',
       controller: 'authController'
     });
 });
```

Anyway, I adopted a boilerplate navigation bar

```
       <nav class="navbar-fluid navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">IoT</a>
           <p class="navbar-text">IoT</p>
           <p class="navbar-right navbar-text" ng-hide="authenticated"><a href="#/login">Login</a> or <a href="#/register">Register</a></p>
           <p class="navbar-right navbar-text" ng-show="authenticated"><a href="#" ng-click="signout()">Logout</a></p>
           <p class="navbar-right navbar-text" ng-show="authenticated">Signed in as {{current_user}}</p>
         </div>
       </nav>
```

And, when I run it on localhost:3000, the homepage address I got instead is

```
 http://localhost:3000/#!/
```

where I was expecting

```
 http://localhost:3000/#/
```

And when I clicked on the 'register' link, the address I got is

```
 http://localhost:3000/#!/#%2Fregister
```

where as I was expecting

```
 http://localhost:3000/#/register
```

Is that normal? Maybe it's bcs of the version of Angular I was using?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

It was all fine before, but then I stripped down the HTML and make the main page pull individual HTML pages one-by-one then this happened.

Comment: Did you try to debug the application. If yes, what it is showing?

Comment: Sams [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139486/angular-routing-ngroute-fails-to-pull-my-other-html-files/41140155#41140155) is correct. Its a breaking change in Angular 1.6

Comment: @GangadharJannu it's working now :)

Comment: @deostroll can you explain this please? so i could avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Change your links from `<a href="#/login">` to `<a href="#!/login">`, `<a href="#">` to `<a href="#!">` etc..

I also have this issue but changing from a hash to hashbang resolves it for me.

Comment: Can you explain why? It's weird that you have to add ! for it to work.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting) will be able to provide a better answer than me about the why. This is a new default behaviour (Although I can't find any documentation to support this). Angular seems to be encouraging the use of SEO friendly links in SPAs.

Comment: Also see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-mode-default-mode-)

Comment: thanks for the links, do you know whether the change in hashbang will affect the backend routing I've written so far in Express?

Comment: I'm not hugely experienced with Express, but it should be alright as long as you're using only using ngRoute to load in templates/controllers across a single page. If you're running express callbacks based on what templates are pulled it could be a bit more of an issue though.

Answer (score 0):

```
App.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {  
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('')

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
        .otherwise('/');
}]);
```

will work see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I'm not sure this will fix your issue. But please try this one.

Change your  route provider by including default parameter.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'main.html',
                controller: 'mainController'
            })
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl: 'login.html',
                controller: 'authController'
            })
            .when('/register', {
                templateUrl: 'register.html',
                controller: 'authController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    });
```

and provide the links like `<a href="#/login">Login</a>`

Comment: Thanks for the help but the solution that Sam Judge posted works!

Comment: I don't know why this ! symbol is used in the href url. I hope the best method to use is default url in angular route provider.

Comment: @Nitheesh: (*from comments*) It seems it is new in Angular 1.6

Comment: Oh. Ok. I have not gone through that yet. Thanks @Mistalis

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
       templateUrl: 'main.html',
       controller: 'mainController'
     })
     .when('/login', {
       templateUrl: 'login.html',
       controller: 'authController'
     })
     .when('/register', {
       templateUrl: 'register.html',
       controller: 'authController'
     })
     .otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/'
     });
});
```

For Sign Out, You should use such as:

```
<p class="navbar-right navbar-text" ng-show="authenticated"><a href="#/" ng-click="signout()">Logout</a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but the solution that Sam Judge posted works!