# Unable to direct to html page in angularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

In my angular app, I want to move to another html page after click on buton but it cannot move to the html page that i expected, 
I configed in route like that:

```
angular.module("abc", ["ngRoute"])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {   
            $routeProvider.when("/checkout", {
                templateUrl: "/checkoutPage.html"
            });           
        });
```

In page html :

```
<a href="#/checkout" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Checkout</a>
```

After I hit on checkout button the link address show like this: 
http://localhost:12312/Index.html#!#%2Fcheckout

Thanks for your help.

Comment: AFAIK your href should be like `<a href="checkout">checkout</a> ` meaing it hsould not have hash.Also add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` to config.

Comment: @Marc **html5mode** requires some serverside setting in config file of a particular server. One other thing is that it will be broken if user refreshes the page if server handling is not done.

Answer (score 1):

Change your href url from `<a href="#/checkout">` to `<a href="#!/checkout">`
Hope this will solve your issue.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use hash in `href`.

```
<a href="checkout">checkout</a>
```

Aside from that better to include `otherwise` in `routeconfiig`.

```
angular.module("abc", ["ngRoute"])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {   
            $routeProvider.when("/checkout", {
                templateUrl: "/checkoutPage.html",
                controller: "..."
            })
            .otherwise("/");
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);           
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Its reading the state not the href tag so don't need to use hash tag for that.

```
<a href="/checkout" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Checkout</a>
```