# Using angular route url formation #!/ issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm following the course [Staying Sharp With AngularJs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNZZbVVUs4Q).

The course put some code in `app.ts`:

```
angular
    .module("NoteWrangler", ["ngRoute"])
    .config(function ($routeProvider: angular.route.IRouteProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/notes", {
                templateUrl: "templates/pages/notes/index.html"
            });
    });
```

Ok, so the links are formed like this:

```
somedomain/index.html/#/myPage
```

But when I try my urls are build like this:

```
somedomain/index.html#!/myPage
```

Why the difference?
Between `".../#/..."` and `"...#!/..."` I mean.
How can I change between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the difference?

Old versions of Angular used `#`.

Some years ago, it was changed to use `#!` so it would play nicely with the (now deprecated) [Google Ajax crawling spec](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

In angular it's called a shebang and works closely with your ngroute class. [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting) contains some elaborate answers