# Angular Controller returns 404 on a Route Parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm building my first web app with Node.js and AngularJs.  My problem lies in this code here:

```
var app = angular.module('Martin', ['ngResource','ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'PageCtrl'
        })
        .when('/etx/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/page.html',
            controller: 'PageCtrl'
        });
}]);

app.controller('PageCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, $resource, $routeParams){
        console.log('Got here');
        var Page = $resource('/api/pages/:id');
        Page.get({ id: $routeParams.id }, function(page){
            $scope.page = page;
        });
    }]);
```

From what I understand, if I were to request /etx/mypage, the function in PageCtrl should be run, but when I try to pull it up in a browser, I get a 404 error and nothing is printed to the console.

I tested it with the home page ('/'), and the controller works fine then.

Comment: which version of angular is this?  unless you use `html5Mode`, the URL for that route is either `#/etx/mypage` or `#!/etx/mypage`, depending on the angular version.

Comment: also, a 404 error implies that the server responded to the request, not angular, so you might have to verify that your server routes are correctly returning your angular app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Claies identified, the problem was I forgot the octothorpe (or hashtag if you want to be less cool) in the URL.  So it should not be `etc/mypage`, but `#/etc/mypage`.  This behavior is less than ideal in many cases (including mine), so I recommend disabling this with [HTML5 mode for links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16678065/5031373).