# ngRoute set base url for all routes

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to add a **base url** to all routes in an *AngularJS* app? Essentially changing its location on the server (kind of, if that makes sense... so it would be accessed not via `/` but via `/something/`).

To add some context, I am trying to place an existing *Angular* app behind some authentication  such that the app would now be accessed at address say `http://mysite/secure` after successful login.

The problem is if I was to load the app at `http://mysite/secure` it works fine (the server will obviously serve up the correct page), but clicking any link would result in a page reload and route to `http://mysite/#newpage` instead of `http://mysite/secure/#newpage`.

Without adding `/secure/` to all of the routes and link element is this possible? Cheers, sorry if that is not worded well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set root location for AngularJS router?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319715/how-to-set-root-location-for-angularjs-router)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Setting the `<base>` HTML5 tag might help.  From the documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location):

> **Relative links**
>
> Be sure to check all relative links, images, scripts etc. You must either specify the url base in the head of your main html file (`<base href="/my-base">`) or you must use absolute urls (starting with /) everywhere because relative urls will be resolved to absolute urls using the initial absolute url of the document, which is often different from the root of the application.
>
> Running Angular apps with the History API enabled from document root is strongly encouraged as it takes care of all relative link issues.

Comment: I tried setting the <base> tag but could not get it to work, the example in the docs appears not even to use it. Based on the second paragraph above, can I conclude, if not for the work required to update all links in my case, that including the additional route value would be better than trying to set a 'global' base url?

Comment: To update all the link, could be useful have a global constant declared with angular and accessible in all pages.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17505414/574147

Comment: I have a <base = '/src/'> which works well for almost everything.  However, I added an additional reference, so I am doing an import as follows:
import { FileUploadModule } from 'primeng/fileupload';

Everything seems to work in Visual Studio, but on running it, I get:
GET http://localhost:59911/src/primeng/fileupload 404 (Not Found)

Is this because of the base tag?  Is there any way to get the import to ignore the base tag and just look in node_modules as it should?

Answer (score 39):

The location for the base href must have trailing /. For example:

```
<base href="location" />
```

will not work. It must be in this format:

```
<base href="location/" />
```

Comment: `<base href="/location/" />` Both those slashes are needed.

Comment: @VictorPiousbox In my app, $cookieStore stopped working (as in being cleared when I refreshed the page) when using "/location/" as baseUrl. Using "location/" worked. No idea why.

Comment: @yngvar, I keep my angular apps behind Apache2 proxy that does some url rewrites, perhaps that's a reason.