# Angular.js Get rid of # in url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking over the tutorial for Angular, and I am trying to get rid of the hash that is in the URL.

I have experimented with setting html5 mode to true. However it does not seem to be routing correctly.

The console says:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/partials/phone-list.html 404 (Not Found)
```

This is the code from my app:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
'ngRoute',
'phonecatControllers'
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider.
    when('/phones', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
      controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
    }).
    when('/phones/:phoneId', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
      controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/phones'
  });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

I am currently just working on the localhost and using node to serve up the pages.

EDIT:
I have read through this question: [Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-symbol-from-angular-js-urls)
however my app seems to have the same code. Not sure what I am missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing the # symbol from angular.js urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-symbol-from-angular-js-urls)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to serve the pages for the `/partials/phone-list.html` route on the server aswell. Not only index.html (or whatever you have). Push state (html5-mode) only works when you already have initiated the application, otherwise how would the browser know where to get the javascript from when you are making a new request?

Hashbang URLs are different because you are actually making a request to the same address and thus nothing needs to be changed on the server.

Edit, also make sure that your links are working properly by checking the first answer here
[ngRoute set base url for all routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768814/angularjs-routing-set-base-url-for-all-routes)

Comment: I'm looking at just making a simple site that only uses angularjs. Similar to the tutorial here: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial Is it possible to get rid of the # in such instance or would i need to use a server sided language as well? Currently just serving the pages up on localhost with the nodejs server.

Comment: I actually don't work with Angular but I know how routing works. You said you are using node so you should have what you need, I would use express to easily setup the appropriate routes. As I said you need to make sure that when you make a server request to /partials/phone-list.html, the server needs to respond with the same files as for your application root (index.html + javascript files).