# How to configure html5 mode true for angular JS application for Tomcat server

Tags: angularjs

My angular application is running on tomcat server in eclipse. I want to use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) to remove '#' sign from URL. But when I did that my page reload is not working.
I found following solution for this.
"**Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html)**"

But I do not know how to do in tomcat server in eclipse. Please point me in right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the Tomcat docs on configuration http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/tomcat-apache-howto.html

Comment: I did not work on server side much. Could you please point me exactly what we need to change

Comment: You'll need to search for your particular version of eclipse/tomcat application server your using to find the configuration file, generally speaking it will be in a folder named conf within the Apache or Tomcat installation folder but this varies depending on which build you're using.  Search for redirection in the link I dropped, I generally use Apache (though I have used Tomcat in the past) with Apache you would use the mod_rewrite module to tell it to rewrite any path to index.html (search the web this is common for things like wordpress or Slim PHP framework redirecting to index.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768814/ngroute-set-base-url-for-all-routes)

short answer.. whatever the root of your site is, you set as a base tag in the head of your index.

```
// Usually base directory is '/'
<base href="root_directory_here" />
```