# Set Angular UI Modal height and width programmatically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/swUY4bprWw2HDILMInn3?p=preview) I have an Angular UI modal that has a related class `the-modal` to set the height and the width, they are initially set at `300px` and `500px` respectively.

What I need is to set the height and the width programmatically when the modal is opened, say at `100px` and `200px`.

I cannot use `ng-class` as I want the user to be able to define the height and width. For example, `newHeight` and `newWidth` below will be taken from a database and used to set the modal dimensions. Any ideas how to make this work?

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller("ctl", function($scope,$uibModal) {


  /*
  * these values are taken from a database
  * and should be used to set the height and width of the modal
  */
  var newHeight = 100;
  var newWidth = 200;


  $scope.open = function () {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: false,
          windowClass: 'the-modal',
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html'
        });

    };

});
```

HTML

```
    <style>
      .the-modal .modal-content{
          width:500px;
          height:300px;
      }
   </style>


  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctl">

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <p>Some content</p>
    </script>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>

   </body>
```

Comment: `I want the user to be able to define the height and width.` how ?

Comment: The high and width will be stored in a database. When the modal loads it will take the values and set them. I adjusted the plunk to be clearer.

Comment: One thing you _could_ do is programmatically generate a style tag with the width and height, and assign the modal a class that you also put into the style tag. Then you'd just have to clean up the style tag on the dom when the modal closes.

Comment: how exactly can I generate programmatically a style tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the best solution, but I think it solves Your problem.

I created directive `adjustModal` with hardcoded height/width values, but You can pass them aswell. If you put this directive on first element in modal template, the parent element will be `.modal-content` so You can change width/height directly using `jqLite`.

modal template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div adjust-modal>
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

directive:

```
app.directive('adjustModal', function() {
      return {
        link: function (scope, element) {
          var height = '100px';
          var width = '100px';
          element.parent().css("width", width)
          element.parent().css("height", height)
        }
      }
    });
```

[working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qAp9JoNFtoIP4DAAGMd6?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Inject the height and width to your modal controller and use `ngStyle`, it will add to any style you may already apply using css.

JS:

```
var newHeight = 400;
var newWidth = 200;

$scope.open = function () {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: false,
        windowClass: 'the-modal',
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        resolve: {
          height: newHeight,
          width: newWidth
        },
        controller: function($scope, height, width) {
          $scope.height = height;
          $scope.width = width;
        }
});
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
<div ng-style="{height: height + 'px', width: width + 'px'};">
    <p>Some content</p> height: {{height}}, width: {{width}}
</script>
```

[Forked plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SOIiw3aYuDZiFultzenC?p=preview)

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. it changes the `content` height/width, and I need to change the `modal` height/width. Also, you're missing the closing `div`.

Comment: maybe `windowTemplateUrl` is what you are looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696224/angular-ui-bootstrap-modal-use-custom-modal-window

Answer (score 1):

If possible, move your controller up to the `html` tag level like [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OerW8u1eDEsbmQYz5whG?p=preview). Then your style tag can change dynamically.

```
   <style>
      .the-modal .modal-content{
          width:{{dimension.newWidth}}px;
          height:{{dimension.newHeight}}px;
      }
   </style>
```

Otherwise, you can create a directive that resizes the parent element like [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gWYi407gK9nqhbsStCCt?p=preview).

Markup:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
  <div parent-dimension="" parent-width="{{vm.width}}" parent-height="{{vm.height}}">
    <p>I am {{vm.width}}px wide and {{vm.height}}px high</p>
  </div>
</script>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('parentDimension', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            var setDimension = function(dimension, val) {
                val = val && parseInt(val);
                if (val) {
                  // Set the dimension of the parent element
                    elem[0].parentNode.style[dimension] = val + 'px';
                }
            };

            // Watch for changes in width and set accordingly
            attr.$observe('parentWidth', function(newVal) {
                setDimension('width', newVal);
            });

            // Watch for changes in height and set accordingly
            attr.$observe('parentHeight', function(newVal) {
                setDimension('height', newVal);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: your solution also works, but I can accept only one answer

Answer (score 0):

Hum, what about adding a new stylesheet line to your CSS that you will be using for your popup modal;

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap']);
    app.controller("ctl", function($scope,$uibModal) {

      /*
      * these values are taken from a database
      * and should be used to set the height and width of the modal
      */
      var newHeight = 100;
      var newWidth = 200;

    var style = document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0];

      $scope.open = function () {
      style.sheet.insertRule(".the-modal-changed .modal-content { height: "+newHeight+"px; width: "+newWidth+"px; background:red; }", 0);

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
              animation: false,
              windowClass: 'the-modal-changed',
              templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html'
            });

        };

    });
```

So I get the content of the current style tag, and added a new style with the rule `.the-modal-changed .modal-content { height: "+newHeight+"px; width: "+newWidth+"px; background:red; }`

This way, `the-modal-changed` class will be the class that you want to use for your modal. So I changed the model's windowClass property to this.

Works just fine, but since I'm sure that you are doing something more complex that what your demo shows, not sure if it would work for your situation. Also I made the background red to demonstration.

[Here is the forked plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/k4iqk2cfBvwIqOBuEq9U?p=preview)

Comment: your solution also works, but I can accept only one answer