# Javascript base site route

Tags: javascript, jquery, base-url

I have this following code

```
jQuery('#main-menu > ul > li.search')
  .append('<ul class="search-box sub-menu"><li><form action="http://####.####.org.uk" id="searchform" method="get"><input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search"></form></li></ul>');
```

It’s specifically this bit I’m interested in

```
<form action="http://####.####.org.uk" id="searchform" method="get">
```

where `####.####.org.uk` is the site index of the site I’m working on, I however need this to not be hardcoded in, and just reference back to the base path, such as `site.com`, this code can be called from anywhere on the site, so could be called from `site.com/fdsifudfa.php`, `site.com/test/test/123/lol.php`, for example. I need this form action to go to `site.com` only.

I don’t want to have a fixed site path in here as this could be anything (code could move around) / be resold.

Comment: then just remove it. a link that links to "index.php" assumes its base path the path from where it is served.

Comment: Would this be true for `site.com/test1/test2/test3/test4.php`, would it not look for `index.php` in the test3 directory?

Comment: a link that links to "/index.php" <- notice the "/" assumes the root. so with "/" it will not look to test3 directory. it will look to the root directory.

Comment: Just remove action attribute.

Comment: just `action="/"` will do. `form` without `action` is not valid

Answer (score 0):

How about using `document.domain` ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at base?

```
<head>
<base href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/" target="_blank">
</head>
```

From

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: depending on your situation, you *may* be opening a big can of worms when you use the `base` tag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag i'm avoiding it like the plague

Comment: Interesting read, we have used it many times and its worked well. We tend to use it in angularjs sites and it works very well and its covered in googles angular docs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768814/ngroute-set-base-url-for-all-routes but allways good to read the why nots :)

Comment: our site can be run from 

`http://host`

or

`http://host/folder`

and it helps us manage that