# $route depend on the current URL ($location)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, symfony, route-provider

in my angularJS app I use symfony as rest API.

Depending on my current url I'm using the $http under app_dev.php or not.
I realized this with the following code:

```
app.run (function( $rootScope, $location ){

    $rootScope.dev = "";
    if ( $location.absUrl().search("app_dev.php") > 0 ) {
        $rootScope.dev = "app_dev.php/";
    }
}

app.controller('OfferIndexCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location, $filter, $rootScope){

    $http.get( $rootScope.dev + 'stage/offer/get').success(function(json){
        $scope.offerList = json.offerList;
    });
}
```

This works fine. But the .run() runs after .config() and its not possible to integrate it into the routeProvider.

Can anyone help me to integrate this into my routeProvider

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function( $routeProvider, $locationProvider ){

            $routeProvider.
                when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'stage/view/offer/index',
                    controller: 'OfferIndexCtrl'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                })
        }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<base>` tag to set base URL for your app, and set your base to "/" or "/app_dev.php/" depending on your Symfony environment, using TWIG helpers for environment. You can use this for "app_test.php" as well.

```
<base href="{{ path('homepage') }}">
```

With this your whole application will just work on that base URL, you don't need anything more.

How base HTML5 tag works with AngularJS application is described in detail here [ngRoute set base url for all routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768814/ngroute-set-base-url-for-all-routes)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm using plain JS befor the Angular part I can use this variable from there.
Following code worked for me:

```
var dev = "";
if ( location.pathname.search("app_dev.php") > 0 ) {
        dev = "app_dev.php/";
        console.log( "App läuft unter dev");
}

App.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function( $routeProvider, $locationProvider ){

        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: dev + 'stage/view/offer/index',
                controller: 'OfferIndexCtrl'
            }).
}
```