# New route re-writes URL to default route, SignalR stops connecting

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I've attempted to add a route in `RouteConfig.cs` called 'CustRoute', the only other route present is the default route.

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "CustRoute",
                url: "{cust}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { cust = new CustConstraint() }
            ).RouteHandler = new CustMvcRouteHandler();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

The URL reverts back to the default one when loading the page. The page loads but I cannot connect to SignalR either. 
For example, if I go to `www.example.com/Cust/Home` it will change the URL to `www.example.com/Home` on loading the page.

Comment: Show how you setup signalR. This looks like a route conflict issue. Also include the custom constraint and route handler

Comment: It was a route conflict issue, but I found it was routing in AngularJS that caused the problem... ngRoute is used in our application and the <base> tag in <head> was only pointing to application path only and not to the route's path. I'll explain this further in an answer.

Comment: I am glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue after some more investigation, it was `ngRoute` in the AngularJS code that caused the problem because the HTML `<base>` tag in the `<head>` element did not account for `/Cust/` in my URL.

ngRoute uses the `<base>` tag to route URLs ([credit to this answer for the info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768814/ngroute-set-base-url-for-all-routes)).

I fixed the issue by changing `<base href="@(Request.ApplicationPath)"/>` to `<base href="@(Request.ApplicationPath + "/" + custName)"/>`.